# I am trying to stretch an image from a mobile first approach using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to gradually scale an image as I widen the page from the smallest width. I am starting from a mobile width and widening the page, but my images remain static.

Here is a site that does what I want my images to do. The images are right below the carousel. I am starting with a mobile first approach.

http://www.sistersoftheblackmoon.com/

here is my html code:

```
<div class="article">
<ul>
<li><img  src="http://www.sistersoftheblackmoon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/column1.jpg" class="image"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and for css I have tried so many different variations of code that I don't even remember.

Comment: Show us what you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into percentage and auto widths for css. I assume by smallest width you mean that you have the browser resized to small initially then as you expand it resizes; if so here's an example:

```
.image_class {
  max-width: 500px; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

You would leave the max-width out if you wanted it to scale on all cases. And then add the css class to the div or whatever that is holding your image.

Comment: I tried using the css you provided but it did not work.  I also added in my html in my original question.  If anything, I will try to work on it more.  I might need to revisit and study the css rules a little further.

Comment: never mind, awesome!  it worked as far as the stretching.  I just changed my html a little and added your css.  Thank you lto A.